# STM32 HAL one of four PWM pins stays high

Tags: pwm, stm32, stm32f10x

I want to use pins A15, B3, B4 and B5 for PWM using Timer2 and Timer3 on STM32F103C8T6. Using code based on one generated by CubeMX i've got pins A15, B3, B4 working properly, but B5 is constantly stuck on high. I tested using normal GPIO, and all four pins can change their states (so it's not issue outside microcontroller)

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();

    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_TIM2_Init();
    MX_TIM3_Init();
    MX_TIM4_Init();

    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1); //A15
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2); //B3
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1); //B4
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2); //B5

    while (1)
    {
        TIM2->CCR1 = 50;
        TIM2->CCR2 = 50;
        TIM3->CCR1 = 50;
        TIM3->CCR2 = 50;
    }   
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
    PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCPCLK2_DIV6;
    if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time
     */
    HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick
     */
    HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

    /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

    htim2.Instance = TIM2;
    htim2.Init.Prescaler = 719;
    htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim2.Init.Period = 99;
    htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/* TIM3 init function */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

    htim3.Instance = TIM3;
    htim3.Init.Prescaler = 719;
    htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim3.Init.Period = 99;
    htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}
```

Comment: Post the 'MX_' functions code to take a look. If I'm right, PB3 is also used for I2C1 and may be some conflict there. Never bet your bottom dollar on Cube Mx.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in your pin configuration. According to the [stm32f103c8t6 datasheet page 28-33](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00161566.pdf), PB5 by default configured as I2C1_SMBAl. PA6 -> TIM3 CH1, PA7 -> TIM3 CH2, PA0 -> TIM2 CH1, PA1 -> TIM2 CH2 are the default pin configurations.

To remap the functions as you want, you have to change AFIO_MARP register. Quoting from [STM32F103x family datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf)

> To optimize the number of peripherals available for the 64-pin or the 100-pin or the 144-pin
>   package, it is possible to remap some alternate functions to some other pins. This is
>   achieved by software, by programming the AF remap and debug I/O configuration register
>   (AFIO_MAPR). In this case, the alternate functions are no longer mapped to their original
>   assignations.

Comment: I tried using your advice, used function __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM3_PARTIAL(), but sadly it didn't help, but seeing from your comment that original function was I2C, I disabled I2C, and PWM started working. Then I checked in [Errata](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/7d/02/75/64/17/fc/4d/fd/CD00190234.pdf/files/CD00190234.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00190234.pdf), and it turned out that is a documented bug with I2C1 and Timer3 enabled at one time.

Comment: That is interesting! Feel free to edit my answer, if you want to include the bug details

Comment: What code exactly did you use to solve the problem?